# Trouble interacting with particular elements, selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, class, xpath

I am working on a program to export historical data of investment funds from yahoo finance. I am very new to selenium (python) and am running into issues regarding some elements that I cannot find an extraction method for. I have looked into grabbing the element using xpath as well as id, name, and class, and am still struggling.

I have code getting me to the webpage I need, but once I need to start clicking buttons, I hit road blocks for all remaining elements I need to interact with. Please see my attached source code, as well as the snips I have showing which elements I am trying to grab in order.

**Note regarding my source code:** I believe there is a more efficient way to time finding an element as opposed to using the time.sleep() function, but I am unfamiliar with how to implement it. In your solutions, I am happy to either see the code that improves upon mine or code that aligns with what I have so far.

My code should navigate you to the url I am working with. All help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

ticker = "FXAIX"

# Declare browser variables
path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

# Open Chrome and go to YF
driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com')
search = driver.find_element_by_id("yfin-usr-qry")
search.send_keys(ticker)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(10)

#Click Historical Data
history = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Historical Data")
history.click()

time.sleep(10)

#Click the Time Period


#Click Max


#Click Apply


#Click Download
```

Snips: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSJud.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ4bx.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works. You have to add wait time after every click for the page to load and element to be visible and clickable

```
ticker = "FXAIX"

#Click on Historic Data link text
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@data-test='HISTORICAL_DATA']/a/span").click()

#Click on dateRange
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Time Period']//following::div[contains(@class,'dateRangeBtn')]").click()

#Click on MAX
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-value='MAX']").click()

#Click on Apply
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button/span[text()='Apply']").click()

#Click on Download
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'"+ticker+"') and @download='"+ticker+".csv']").click()
```

Comment: I added the wait commands and this executed perfectly. Thank you so much for this solution!